# What is a "calling context?"

Tags: javascript, ecma262

ECMA-262 5.1 subsections [10.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2) and [10.4.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2.1) refer to a "calling context." This doesn't appear to be described anywhere else in the document.

Quoting the spec, emphasis mine:

> 10.4.2 Entering Eval Code
>
> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution context for eval code:
>
> 1. If there is no **calling context** or if the eval code is not being evaluated by a direct call (15.1.2.1.1) to the eval function then,

> 10.4.2.1 Strict Mode Restrictions
>
> The eval code cannot instantiate variable or function bindings in the variable environment of the **calling context** that invoked the eval if either the code of the **calling context** or the eval code is strict code. Instead such bindings are instantiated in a new VariableEnvironment that is only accessible to the eval code.

- What does "calling context" mean in these paragraphs? I would assume it refers to the [Execution Context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) at the top of the stack just before `eval` is called; can anyone verify this?
- What does it mean to have "no calling context?" Can someone provide an example of code or conditions that could result in a call to `eval` with no calling context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "calling context" refers to the context which the native `eval` function is being called from.

If you are executing `eval` from some native code (for example, you run a native function which executes code when completed using `eval` for some reason or another), then it would have no context, which is then specified to run under the global scope. The context only refers to ECMAScript executable code.

However, the calling context refers to the variables and directives in the execution context of where it is called. For example, it only knows that eval is meant to work as strict code if it checks the calling context.

This is clarified by a very similar question in the ES-Discuss mailing list, where **Brendan Eich** (the creator of JavaScript) responds:

### [How can eval code not have a calling context?](http://esdiscuss.org/topic/how-can-eval-code-not-have-a-calling-context)

> ES3 says:
>
> > #### 10.2.2 Eval Code
> >
> > When control enters an execution context for
> >     eval code, the previous active execution context, referred to as the
> >     calling context, is used to determine the scope chain, the variable
> >     object, and the this value. If there is no calling context, then
> >     initialising the scope chain, variable instantiation, and
> >     determination of the this value are performed just as for global code.
>
> I am baffled by "If there is no calling context". How could the
>   possibility arise? How would `eval` get called if no one calls it?

#### [Response:](http://esdiscuss.org/topic/how-can-eval-code-not-have-a-calling-context)

> A call from native code, the "host" program.
>
> Some browsers support indirect `eval`, allowing this:
>
> ```
> setTimeout(eval, 0, "alert('hi mom')");
> ```
>
> The window used is the one in which `setTimeout` was found along the
>   scope chain, so
>
> ```
> myFrame.setTimeout(eval, 0, "alert(x)");
> ```
>
> should show `myFrame.x`, not the calling frame or window's `x`.

Note: `myFrame` in this instance refers to the frame's global scope.

Comment: This sounds about right to me, although I think the "global scope" part is off; the global scope has an execution context ("When control is transferred to ECMAScript executable code, control is entering an execution context."). Good point about execution context only applying to script; maybe the console calls `eval` with no calling context, for example. This might be a "your guess is as good as mine" scenario, unfortunately, since there's no definitive description of "calling context" in the spec. Let's see if any other answers pop up.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: I think where it is used in the strict mode section is a bit more clear, that was how I was thinking of it from.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: some google-fu found something pretty close to an official response, is that better?

Comment: Whoa, ES3 is *way* more specific about what a calling context actually is. I think I feel another question brewing. Still reading through this...

Comment: If you downvoted this post, could you please explain how could I improve this post or what's wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: I'd also be interested in hearing an explanation for the downvote. I felt like this answer covered everything, but if something is missing I'd like to hear it.

Comment: This answer is solid and correct. Whoever downvoted it must have been angry with you personally @Qantas94Heavy